# Trying to refer to a final ImageView does not work

Tags: java, android, imageview

my problem is that i cannot refer to my final imageView (created in onCreate) from another method. 
What i want to do is saving picture paths in an array and change the picture of the imageView with an onTouchListener.
I get the error "imageView cannot be resolved". I tried a lot of things but nothing works. I can find my imageView in R and xml.

I try to work with my imageView in a new method nextCard():

```
public void nextCard() {
  rdmGenerated = randomZahl(0, 52);     
  rdmConverted = (int)rdmGenerated;
  imageView.setImageResource(card[rdmConverted]);
}
```

My onCreate looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                nextCard();
            }
        });
}
```

My card array looks like this:

What could be wrong? I checked case sensitive and already cleaned and builded a hundret times. Maybe it has something to do with the method-declaration (public void wrong for using final variables?)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem few days ago. What I did was, i made the variable static to be able to refer it to all the methods i wish to access that variable with. E.g : if suppose i wish to access ImageView i declare as :

```
private static ImageView imageView;
```

Then once in onCreate it gets initialised, hopefully it should be available to all other methods..
and this declaration is to be done before onCreate in the activity itself (if incase you wondering where to declare) hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what i was searching for and now it runs ;)!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared imageView within the onCreate method, therefore it only has local scope. Try declaring imageView as a class member.

Lazy pseudo

Class Something

private ImageView imageView;

oncreate() method
imageView =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);